# {∅} ⊆ {{∅}}\{∅}. True or false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is this true or false?
I was thinking if we substract {∅} on the right side, only the empty set will be left. And {∅} can‘t be a subset(eq) of ∅. Is this true?

Comment: In this cas, $A=\{\{\emptyset\}\}, B=\{\emptyset\}$ then $A\cap B=\emptyset,$ so $A\setminus B=A.$

Comment: Sade, since you asked a very low-quality question, it would better if you removed it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) The notation $U\setminus V$ means "all elements that are in $U$ but not in $V$".

$\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ has just one element, namely $\{\emptyset\}$. And $\{\emptyset\}$ also has just one element, namely $\emptyset$. So these two sets have no elements in common.

So $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ is just $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

(ii) The notation $U\subseteq V$ means "all elements of $U$ are also elements of $V$".

So $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\{\{\emptyset\}\}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ means $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, from (i); which means $\emptyset$ is an element of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

What do you think? Is this true?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It‘s false of course.

Comment: Since it is a very low-quality question, it would better if you removed your answer before the question is closed.

Comment: @Angelo: let them close it if they must. Jeez. Aren't we allowed to help people?